# query_string not working for uppercase string in ElasticSearch

Tags: php, elasticsearch

```
'query' => array(
                    'query_string' => array(
                        'fields'=> array('name'),
                        "analyze_wildcard" => true,
                        'query' => '*tom*'
                    )
                )
```

I use this query phrase in php program,and It match lowercase strings, 
eg: tom/test/1 , but 'Tom/test/2' is not matched, I tried
 'query' => '*Tom*' also not worked.
Any suggestions? 
Thanks a lot.

Comment: It depends on what you have in the index. If the indexed value is upper case, then it won't match.

Comment: Try `'query' => '\"Tom\"'`.

Answer (score 0):

How about changing the line

```
'query' => '*tom*'
```

to

```
strtolower('query') => strtolower('*tom*')
```

I've not tested that - so it may not work, but in theory, set both sides of the equation to lowercase and it should ignore case.

Comment: Thanks for you anwser, but not working, 

`
  "query":{"query_string":{"fields":[ "name"],"analyze_wildcard":true,"query":"*tom*"}}}}
`